# css @print media showing spaces for hidden contents angularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an angular SPA. Main page is divided into 2 parts - left and right (both have separate scrolls). Left portion have links and right portion displays data for those links.

This is main CSS.

```
#left, #right {
    overflow-y: scroll
}
#left {
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 25%;
    height: 75%;
}
#right {
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 0;
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
    height: 75%
}

html, body {
    margin: 0; padding:0; border: 0;
    overflow: hidden
}

#printSection {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Right portion contains a div - #printSection, and a button print. I want to print data of #printSection while user clicks on print button. print css is -

```
body {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-family: Times,"Times New Roman",Garamond, serif;
}
body * {
    visibility:hidden;
}
#printSection, #printSection * {
    visibility:visible;
}
#printSection {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

Every thing is fine except clicking on print button showing empty pages for left section data first then the #printSection data.

Why this empty pages are coming for left section data?? Please help me. If you need any more inputs please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
visibility: hidden
```

Keeps your elements in the document flow, and just hides any content. This is the cause of your problem.

```
display: none
```

Removes the elements from the document flow completely.

Comment: You mean to say in body* of print.css, i should use  display: none. If yes then i tried that also. with  display: none nothing is coming for print.

Comment: You could try changing the, "visibility: visible" rule  to "display: block" as well, but that is probably going to cause you issues (not everything is a block element). I would suggest re-working your selectors, instead of hiding everything in the body, then trying to override that - simply display none the section you wish to not print. And make no mistake, display none, is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Angular way you can achieve this instead of CSS

If you don't want to store element in DOM(in your case) use ng-if like

in controller:

```
 $scope.showdivVar=true;
```

View:

```
<div ng-if="showdivVar"></div>
```